# Magento 1.9 How to remove values from Products, where the Attribute is no longer in the Attribute Set?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, database, product-attribute

I have a product *P* in attribute set *S* where a value is set to attribute *A*.

If I now remove attribute *A* from the attribute set *S*, the value for *A* of *P* remains in the database as long as I don't completely remove the attribute *X* itself.

How can I remove these values so that the function `hasData()` of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` returns `false`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested and may not work:

```
$productAttributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getEditableAttributes($product);
foreach ($product->getData() as $code=>$value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($code, $productAttributes) {
        $product->setData($code, null);
    }
}
$product->save();
```